Using subprocess.check_call with pip install —trusted-host
In Python (vsCode): I have my code working but to make it share-able and do not want an executable. The problem is that in order to install pptx, we need to use the --trusted-download ***** in the pip command. So I tried to add to the subprocess.check_call. How can I get this working?
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    from pptx import Presentation
except ImportError: 
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", '--trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user python-pptx'])
    # how to manually install
    # pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user python-pptx
finally:
    from pptx import Presentation

I get the following error on a computer without PPTX installed. I want my script to automatically install PPTX if not already done so. But it needs the --trusted-download flag. (subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'pptx'] does not work)
C:\****\test\test> ****.py
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\test\test\****.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pptx import Presentation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\****\test\test\****.py", line 14, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", '--trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user python-pptx'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user python-pptx']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\****\test\test\****.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pptx import Presentation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'


You need to split up the parameters to pip into separate elements of the list you're passing to subprocess.check_call().  All three spaces in that last, huge element are places where it should have been split.
